# How to use "fsolve" for optimizing the objective function?

Tags: matlab, optimization

How can I optimize the below function using "fsolve". It only takes input argument in the form of vectors but I have to pass input arguments to the below function in the form of matrix.

I am getting the below error while using the optimization toolbox

Error running optimization. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

```
 function f = object(w)
 k=10;
 B=20;
 f = sum ((w(1,:)/(w(2,:).^w(3,:)*k)+((w(3,:)-1)*w(4,:)/B*w(3,:))));
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very brief in your problem description about the outer circumstances but from your function it looks like the function might expect a `w` argument of size `4 x N`. Did I guess correctly? If so, try

```
w_initial = rand(4*N,1); % resonable initialization. maybe random? maybe zeros?
fsolve(@(w) object(reshape(w,4,N)), w_initial, ...)
```